# Subset of columns of a CSV file in R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file with 200 columns, I need

```
ts,column1,column2,column3,....
```

I need to select all columns except "ts" using subset command..

```
myCSVFile=read.csv("myFile.csv")
```

How to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

`subset(myCSVFile, select=-ts)`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.